# valid characters in Postgres Ltree label in utf8 charset

Tags: postgresql, ltree

the doc of Postgres Ltree said that

> A label is a sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscores (for example, in C locale the characters A-Za-z0-9_ are allowed). Labels must be less than 256 bytes long.

However, it does not said that if we set the locale to 'en_US.UTF-8', what is the valid character can be used in Postgres Ltree. So, can dash(hyphen) be used in the label of Ltree?

Comment: The fact that it mentions the locale means that it'll be in the current locale's encoding, so yes, if the database is UTF-8 you can use UTF-8 chars.

Comment: @CraigRinger, yes i have test that i can even insert a chinese  char.

Comment: @andy Any luck on using hypen (-) inside a ltree label?

Comment: @Charizard_ Sorry for not updating the answer. Yes,  i have finally figured out that it is one of our DBA that changed the source of **ltree** and recompile it with supporting the dash(-) char. We have a single table with more than 6B records

Comment: FYI Postgres 16 will include support for `-` via [this patch](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/b1665bf01e5f4200d37addfc2ddc406ff7df14a5) which was merged recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for not updating the answer.

Yes, i have finally figured out that it is one of our DBA that changed the source of **ltree** and recompile it with supporting the **dash(-)** char. We have a single table with more than 6B records.

Comment: Since you have more than 6B records, is there any problem with including the dash? Or is everything good? Just wanted to know why the label restriction was put in the first place. And also do you have the patch hosted somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: @Charizard Yes, everything is good, i do not know why the author of **ltree** do not have it in the original source code. The patch is very simple. You can have a look at [the source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ltree_8h.html#a1cb5d5dd0c364d720854e8a250967dd1), i.e., the 83 line of [ltree.h](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ltree_8h_source.html)

Comment: I'll try to submit patch request and wish it gets accepted

Comment: just wonder if someone has re-compiled it as a separate extension or if there's any tutorial about how to re-compile the ltree module, we want to support the dash as well

Comment: FYI Postgres 16 will include support for `-` via [this patch](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/b1665bf01e5f4200d37addfc2ddc406ff7df14a5) which was merged recently.